# react setState get wrong status

Tags: reactjs, status

I've recently begun to learn React and here's a problem that I found.
What I tried to do here is :

1. set the number to 0 as the initial state.
2. change the state with the number I passed in.
3. print the state again.

Here is the code:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number:0,
    };
  }

 changeNum(num){
    console.log('num pass in is: '+num);
    console.log('before, the num is: ' + this.state.number);
    this.setState({number: num});
    console.log('now the point chosen is: ' + this.state.number);
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={()=>this.changeNum(1)}>Click</button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

These codes will start as:

- num pass in is: 1
- before, the num is: 0
- now the point chosen is: 0

And then it shows:

- num pass in is: 1
- before, the num is: 1
- now the point chosen is: 1

There's no doubt that the number has been passed in, but it seems not been got from the last `this.state.number`

What I expect is the output:

- num pass in is: 1
- before, the num is: 0
- now the point chosen is: 1

What is the cause of this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is `async`, it will take time to update the state. Use [callback](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) in `setState`, which will execute when `setState` completes it's execution.

```
this.setState({
   number: num
}, () => console.log('now the point chosen is: ' + this.state.number));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4hjvge)

Comment: Thank you ravibagul91 for the explanation. I understand it now~ :)

Answer (score 0):

set state using prevState which is the most recommended way.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
 num: prevState.number = num,
})).
```